# Kusto query how to iterator each row in a table as parameter to query in another table?

Tags: kql

I have two 'PlayersNames' and 'PlayerSpendMondy'
How can I iterator 'PlayersNames' get each PlayerName then get how much money spend on each player?
Does Kusto query support this?

```
let PlayerName = datatable(name:string)
[
   'player1',
   'player2',
   'player3',
];
let PlayerSpendMoney = datatable(name:string, spendMoney:int)
[
    'player1', 1,
    'player2', 3,
    'player3', 4,
    'player1', 1,
    'player2', 5,
    'player3', 1,
    'player3', 1,
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that using the [`join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer).

For example:

```
let PlayerName = datatable(name:string)
[
   'player1',
   'player2',
   'player3',
]
;
let PlayerSpendMoney = datatable(name:string, spendMoney:int)
[
    'player1', 1,
    'player2', 3,
    'player3', 4,
    'player1', 1,
    'player2', 5,
    'player3', 1,
    'player3', 1,
]
;
PlayerName
| join kind=leftouter  (
    PlayerSpendMoney
    | summarize sum(spendMoney) by name
) on $left.name == $right.name
| project name, sum_spendMoney
```

```
| name    | sum_spendMoney |
|---------|----------------|
| player1 | 2              |
| player2 | 8              |
| player3 | 6              |
```